# Problem with Pointer Arithmetic using Classes

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am experimenting with Pointers and can't figure out why this won't work.
I know that I am supposed to be using STL containers instead of using raw pointers but I am curious as to why this is not working.

Suppose that we have a class like this

```
class Example
{
public:
    Example()
        :number{10}
    {
        std::cout << "From Example Class " << std::endl;
    }
    ~Example()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor from Example Class" << std::endl;
    }
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "Number from Example : " << number << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int number{};
};
```

We initialize a pointer to array of pointers like this

```
// Pointer to array of pointers
Example** ex_ptr_array{ new Example * [4] };
for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    ex_ptr_array[i] = new Example{};
}
```

I can dereference a pointer by doing this and I can call the objects method without using `->` operator.

```
(*ex_ptr_array[0]).print();
// Prints Number from Example : 10
```

I can also use the array style and use `->` operator to call the objects method.

```
ex_ptr_array[2]->print();
// Prints Number from Example : 10
```

But I dont understand why the Pointer Arithmetic will not work

```
// Why doesnt this work?
(*ex_ptr_array + 1)->print();
// Prints some random value
// Number from Example : -33686019
```

Comment: The dereference operator `*` takes precedence over the plus operator `+`, so you need a pair of parentheses like this: `(*(ex_ptr_array + 1))->print();`.

Comment: Eeew, why manual memory management with `new`? In modern C++ use containers and/or smart pointers. Naked `new`/`delete` is a serious code smell.

Answer (score 0):

> (*ex_ptr_array + 1)->print();

You're dereferencing `ex_ptr-array` first, and then adding one. Do it the arithmetic before the dereference:

(*(ex_ptr_array + 1))->print();

The compiler knows the size of the type held in `ex_ptr_array`, so when you add 1 to the pointer, it actually increments the pointer by the size of that type.